# What are the use-cases for blobs with Mime type "text/html"?

Tags: javascript, blob

There are many use-case examples for blob with Mime types `text/javascript`, `application/json`, `image/...`, etc

MDN [Bolob() Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#examples) also shows:

```js
const array = ['<q id="a"><span id="b">hey!</span></q>']; // an array consisting of a single string
const blob = new Blob(array, { type: "text/html" }); // the blob
```

Above example contains an HTML fragment?

- Can it be appended to DOM in any way (as `Blob` or after getting an object URL)?

*(Please provide code snippet examples to show the use-case.)*

**N.B.** The question is not about what Mime type is. The focus is specifically on use-cases for the aforementioned.

## Update

As per request from Bergi:

##### Use-case for Blob `{type: "text/javascript"}`

```js
// import module
(async () => {

  const response = await fetch('module url');
  const blob = await response.blob(); 
  // Blob { size: 10176, type: "text/javascript" }
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const obj = import(url);

})();
```

##### Use-case for Blob `{type: "application/json"}`

Subject to [Import Attributes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes)

```js
// import JSON
(async () => {

  const blob = new Blob(['{ .... }'], {type: 'application/json'});
  // Blob { size: 10176, type: "application/json" }
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const obj = import(url, {with: {type: 'json'}});
  
})();
```

##### Use-case for Blob `{type: "image/..."}`

```js
// include remote image
(async () => {

  const response = await fetch('image url');
  const blob = await response.blob(); 
  // Blob { size: 10176, type: "image/png" }
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = objectURL;
  document.body.appendChild(img);

})();
```

Comment: The use case is storing HTML. What is unclear here?

Comment: How would it be different than storing it as a text variable? The HTML data is in `string` format in the blob.

Comment: "text/javascript" and "application/json" can also be a text variable. Why is HTML any different?

Comment: Can it  be inserted into DOM? Blobs with mime type "text/javascript", "application/json" can be imported.

Comment: "*There are many use-case examples for blob with Mime types text/javascript, application/json, image/..., etc*" - what are these? Please show us what use cases for blobs in general you know so that we can answer based on your misunderstandings. Currently it's not quite clear why you think there are use cases for blobs with one mime type but not for an other.

Comment: Just from the top of my head, uploading blobs with form submission or creating object urls from them and embedding them in an iframe would make sense with mime type `text/html` as well

Comment: The spirit of Stack Overflow is contributing useful questions and answers to the Q&A repository and also voting on questions/answers based on their quality and usefulness for other programmers. And as such, meta info like complains about downvotes don't belong into the question.

Comment: @Bergi Post updated with examples.

Comment: Exactly. Each is allowed to vote as they see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Blobs with "text/html" MIME type can be used to store and transmit HTML content representing web pages. This allows you to dynamically generate or fetch HTML content and display it in a web browser.

---

updated:

An example for `<iframe>` so that you can display or inject HTML content from a blob with "text/html" MIME type into the DOM of a web page.

```
// Assuming you have retrieved the blob
var blob = ...;

// Create a Blob URL
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Create an <iframe> element
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

// Set the src attribute to the Blob URL
iframe.src = blobUrl;

// Append the <iframe> to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: How can it be displayed and/or injected into DOM?

Comment: Thank you. Therefore, like `Blob {type: "image/..."}`, it can be used as `src`, but that should  only be useful if the blob contains a complete webpage. It wont be useful for an HTML fragment like the one in the MDN example.

Comment: Certainly! By injecting HTML fragments into the DOM without relying on a blob with "text/html" MIME type as the src attribute, you have more flexibility and control over how you integrate the HTML fragments into your web page.